# Basis and dimension of the subspace of solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider
>   $$
> A =\left( \begin{matrix} 
> 1 & -1 & 0 & -2 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
> \end{matrix}
> \right)
> $$
>   and find a basis and the dimension of $S(A,0)$, where $S(A,0)$ is the subspace of all the solutions $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to the linear equations $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.

We need to solve:
$$w-x-2z=0$$
$$y-z=0$$
So for any $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ we get $w=\lambda$, $x=\lambda - 2\mu$, $y=\mu$, $z=\mu$.

Does this mean that $S(A,0)$ is spanned by two vectors? For example;

- $\lambda = 1, \mu = 0$ gives the vector $(1,1,0,0)$
- $\lambda = 0, \mu = 1$ gives the vector $(0,-2,1,1)$

So then the dimension of $S(A,0)$ would be 2?

Comment: All looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that one can easily check what the dimension of $S$ (usually called the null space) is going to be.

For an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) states that $\operatorname{Rank}(A) + \operatorname{Null}(A) = n$.

In this case, $n = 4$, and $\operatorname{Rank}(A) = 2$ since it is already in echelon form.